# Unable to boot after installing Ubuntu grub rescue. Prompt

Tags: grub2

I have deleted Ubuntu partition from windows grub rescue command appears. Now I have installed Ubuntu using usb and when I tried to reboot again grub rescue appears unknown file system...I have ext4 in a partition and gave it as set and reset while typing insmod normal it shows error what can I do now to boot to Ubuntu

Comment: You haven't provided details of which release of Ubuntu you are using. Some releases allow you to set which device is used for `grub`, so if you use a drive not defined in your BIOS/UEFI as the boot device, the old `grub` will still be used (so grub rescue from the deleted partition is to be expected). More details of your install are needed (release; what install options, or details of your drive options/hardware).  Specifics of the error would also allow us to better understand your issue.

Comment: If you reinstalled Ubuntu in same boot mode, UEFI or BIOS as first install then you should not get grub rescue. It seems you are booting the old install's grub still. That should have been overwritten with new install. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair